# How to synchronize rotation on multiple images in JavaFX Canvas

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have multiple objects that I want to draw rotated together. When they are at 0 degrees (facing straight), they are good, but when they aren't, it looks like this:

[image: Wierdness]

I am using this code to rotate:

```
private void rotate(GraphicsContext gc, double angle, double px, double py) {
    Rotate r = new Rotate(angle, px, py);
    gc.setTransform(r.getMxx(), r.getMyx(), r.getMxy(), r.getMyy(), r.getTx(), r.getTy());
}

private void drawRotatedImage(GraphicsContext gc, Image image, double angle, double tlpx, double tlpy) {
    gc.save(); // saves the current state on stack, including the current transform
    rotate(gc, angle, tlpx + image.getWidth() / 2, tlpy + image.getHeight() / 2);
    gc.drawImage(image, tlpx, tlpy);
    gc.restore(); // back to original state (before rotation)
}
```

I have an array of images that I use and rotate them by calling `drawRotatedImage` using one unified angle. All the images are `32 x 32`.
How can I fix this shift in the images?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. The code rotates the images around their respective centers, if I test it...

Comment: @fabian There is one degree variable. There is a list of Images to be displayed using that variable. They are all 32 x 32. They have a specifix `x` and `y` coordinate to draw at. I draw them at that coord and rotate the image. How can I make it so they rotate as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate the images as a group, simply use the same transformation for all those images:

Instead of

```
gc.save();
gc.setTransform(new Affine(new Rotate(angle, image1CenterX, image1CenterY)));
gc.drawImage(image1, image1X, image1Y);
gc.restore();

gc.save();
gc.setTransform(new Affine(new Rotate(angle, image2CenterX, image2CenterY)));
gc.drawImage(image2, image2X, image2Y);
gc.restore();

...
```

(which is what you're doing, if you call `drawRotatedImage` for each image)

Use

```
gc.save();
gc.setTransform((new Affine(new Rotate(angle, rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY)));

gc.drawImage(image1, image1unrotatedX, image1unrotatedY);
gc.drawImage(image2, image2unrotatedX, image2unrotatedY);
...

gc.restore();
```

Comment: What is `rotationCenterX` and `rotationCenterY` going to be?

Comment: It worked, thanks! I used the starting x and y as `rotationCenterX` and `rotationCenterY`. Would using the center work better? Or the end?

Comment: @theTechnoKid U want to rotate all nodes around some point.What point you need is up to you.If you use `P=(x,y)` as pivot point(=rotation center),you'd get the same effect as if you moved the object you paint by `-P`,rotate around the origin and move the result by `P`.Simply decide which point should keep the position during the rotation(assuming something was painted at that location).Reasonable choices of pivot points could be a intersection of the grid lines,the center of a grid field(imgs align with grid fields after rotations by multiples of 90°).When in doubt,use the center of the grid.